# A dilemma regarding torque when a body moves in circular motion

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, angular-velocity

Consider a mass 'm' tied to a rope and I am rotating it in a circular path with constant angular speed.One component of the tension balances the weight and the other component provides centripetal force which in turn provides centripetal acceleration.Since there is constant angular speed there is no tangential acceleration.There is no air drag and all forces are balanced and since it is uniform circular motion,net torque is zero.

Now here is the real confusion for me.Now the mass 'm' accelerates in the circular path and thus there is an angular acceleration and thus tangential acceleration.There must be a torque which is responsible for this angular acceleration but which force provides this torque?The centripetal force surely can't as it passes through the axis of rotation and hence zero torque!A torque can't magically appear out of no where and cause an angular acceleration right?!

Comment: Which force provides it? What ever force you choose, you have stated its now non uniform circular motion...so you provide the torque. Now if ur talking about a person swinging the string, then speeding up, it is caused by tension, and moving the string "infront" of the center of rotation. We do it automatically without thinking

Comment: This sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*"Now the mass 'm' accelerates in the circular path and thus there is an angular acceleration and thus tangential acceleration"*

The problem starts from above . The mass *m* accelerates as it's velocity vector is changing . However , it's **speed** is constant . Hence , there is no angular and tangential acceleration. And hence , there is no torque . It seems like you are treating *acceleration* and *tangential acceleration* as same ( which aren't) .

Answer (score 0):

> Now the mass 'm' accelerates in the circular path and thus there is an angular acceleration and thus tangential acceleration.

Your question is very unclear. Masses don’t just accelerate. There is a reason that they accelerate that you have not described. There are several possibilities, but I will mention two:

1. the pivot point is displaced away from the center slightly so that the tension is not purely radial. It has a small tangential component which provides tangential and angular acceleration.
2. while remaining perfectly on-center the string is pulled inwards so the radius shortens. In this case the moment of inertia reduces so by conservation of momentum there is angular acceleration without any torque

Comment: In the first possibility you mentioned is law of conservation of angular momentum violated?

Answer (score 0):

Angular acceleration is the rate of change of the rate of angular velocity (relative to the point that the angle is measured from). If the string revolves with constant angular velocity it has no angular acceleration by definition, just as if a car drives down the street at constant linear velocity it has no linear acceleration by definition.

Torques can sort of "appear out of nowhere", but only if you're changing your frame of reference. This is because different points measure different angles in a way that doesn't lend itself to linear composition of angular velocities. More correctly, torques can appear *out of forces* when you re-define the origin of your coordinate space.

For instance, consider a train that comes to a stop relative to the station. Measured by a rat between the the rails, the train and the track both have a constant angular velocity of zero, so there is zero torque. The track is standing still relative to the rat, and the train is coming straight at him. Measured by an observer a safe distance back on the platform, the track's angular velocity is still zero, but the train's angular velocity is nonzero and decreasing, so the train and the track apply equal and opposite torques to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The example is similar to the olympic hammer throw. The athlete increases the tangential speed of the hammer by increasing the angular speed of his hands around his body. That is: the center of rotation is not the hand where one of the ends of the cable are located, but somewhere in the body.

Theoretically, only to keep the hammer with a constant angular velocity without any drag, the center of the rotation could be the athlete's hand, by using an appropriate frictionless coupling.